# The distance between two points function in array C++

Tags: c++

I am having problems understanding what this function is doing, I know its related to finding the distance between two points but I don't see exactly how that is happening...

```
double closestPoints(double points[], int n)
{
double closest = 100.0;

for (int p1 = 0; p1 < n; p1++)
{
    for (int p2 = 0; p2 < n; p2++)
    {
        if (p1 != p2 && abs(points[p1] - points[p2]) < closest)
        {
            closest = abs(points[p1] - points[p2]);
        }
    }
}
return closest;
}
```

Could someone help me understand it?

Comment: What don't you understand in particular? We can't make any premise of what you already know or not.

Comment: How about [learning how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Because then you can more easily figure out what's happening in the code (for example by stepping through it in a debugger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so with 2 for-statements you just pick all combinations of points (so combine every point with every other).

`if(p1 != p2)` means that if p1 points to the same point as p2 does, you ignore them (because you cannot calculate distance between one point.

`abs(points[p1] - points[p2]) < closest` if distance between 2 chosen points is less than current minimum distance, you set your current minimum distance to this distance.

ps. note that `abs(points[p1] - points[p2])` is a formula to calculate distance between to points on a line.

Answer (score 0):

This code is taking an array of doubles and finding which of the `points` is closest together and recording how close they piston. Instead of `double closest = 100` you could do `double closest = abs(points[0] - points[1]);`

Comment: I think by `100`  OP sort of means `INT_MAX`

Comment: @user0042 dont mock Mr. Riddle for knowing very little.

Comment: Are you sure that's what it's doing?